# How to dynamically change doctrine queries in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Lets say, I have a class Movie with a Orm\OneToMany relation ship to the class Actors.

I have already a working example of an getter for $movie->getActors(); which will return all actors of that movie.

But how to dynamically modify the query for that? For example, I show a list of all actors of the movie, and allow the user to sort by name, age, gender, whatever.

**===== EDIT ======**

After learning, that such things belongs to the repository class (thanks to Yoshi, scoolnico), here is the adapted question:

Lets say, I have got a Movie ID 4711. I will fetch the movie:

```
$movie = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository("Movie")
    ->find(4711);
```

And now, I need to get all Actors from this movie sorted by name (as an example).

```
$actorsOfMovie = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository("Actor")
    ->findBy(array("movie_id" => 4711), array('name'=>'asc'));
```

Is this really the correct way?
With this version, I need to know in the controller, how the relationship between movie and actors work! Thats a thing, doctrine should handle for me!

And how to use it with multiple movies?

```
// Controller
$movies = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository("Movie")
    ->findfindBy(array());
return $this->render("xyz.html.twig", array("movies": $movies));

// Twig: xyz.html.twig
{% for movie in movies %}
    <h1>{% movie.getName() %}</h1>
    <p>Actors: {% for actor in movie.getActorsOrderByName() %}{{ actor.getName() }},{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Queries like that should be on the repository not the entity. That's why it's hard to do.

Comment: Ah. ok. But how to get the repository from the entity? For example, if i have the entity $movie, how to get the repository of Movie?

Comment: Ok, no. That's the whole point, your entity should not do such work. If what is initialised by doctrine issn't enough, then do it somewhere else. E.g. In the controller get the repository and have that return the correct entites.

Comment: i have modified my question

Comment: So, let me clarify, have you set up a proper associations between Movie/Actor using [doctrine's association mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)? If not then, no offence, your question too broad. Because that would really be the first step to do. Done correctly, your movie entity will *know* what it's actors are.

Comment: Yes, I have. I can call $movie->getActors() and it returns me the actors. My last code example (the twig example) works with movie.getActors() already. I know, that I can add annotations for sorting to the class, but I need the possibility to switch sorting Direction, etc.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Personally I would probably implement a view helper which whould then order the list inside the view directly. No need to have that kind of logic bound to an entity.

Comment: First thing is, that sorting data is a task for database and not for views. The other point is, that the view solution works maybe for sorting, but not for filtering, since you need to fetch all items first, and then filter it. I have found now an article with a similar problem: https://www.boxuk.com/insight/blog-posts/filtering-associations-with-doctrine-2

Comment: I disagree, but if you have found a solution, don't hesitate to post it as an answer, so that future readers can profit from it.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create a specific function in your class Repository:

```
class MovieRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   public function getActoryByGender($gender)
   { 
       /.../
   }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
/.../
$em = $this->getDoctrine()>getManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Movie');
$actors = $repository->getActorByGender('male');
/.../
```

Comment: i have modified my question, since i learned from you (and yoshi), that repositories are the right way, but it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for this is to use doctrine's Criteria class (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections).

Have a look at https://www.boxuk.com/insight/blog-posts/filtering-associations-with-doctrine-2

Based on this, I can do the following:

```
// In the Movie Class
/**
 * Get actors
 *
 * @param array $options
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getActors($options = array())
{
    if(!$options) {
        return $this->actors;
    }

    $criteria = Criteria::create();

    if(isset($options["order_by"])) {
        $criteria->orderBy($options["order_by"]);
    }
    if(isset($options["limit"])) {
        $criteria->setMaxResults($options["limit"]);
    }
    if(isset($options["offset"])) {
        $criteria->setFirstResult($options["offset"]);
    }
    // Or I can define other filters or sorting stuff
    if(..) {
        ...
    }

    return $this->actors->matching($criteria);
}
```